# Force logout in ASP.NET MVC Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm using ASP.Net MVC Core where I have the following code where it is a daily task that sets users as "Expired" if their subscription is over.
But how can I also check and force them to logout if they are currently logged in?

```
   public interface IExpirationJob
{
    Task SetExpired();
}

public class ExpirationJob : IExpirationJob
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
    private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;

    public ExpirationJob(ApplicationDbContext db, IEmailSender emailSender)
    {
        _db = db;
        _emailSender = emailSender;
    }

    public async Task SetExpired()
    {
        foreach(var item in _db.Institution)
        {
            if (item.SubscriptionEndDate != null)
            {
                if (item.SubscriptionEndDate == DateTime.Today) 
                {
                    item.Status = SD.StatusExpired;

                  //Here I want to check if the user is logged in, then force logout should be done. 

                }
            }
        }
        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What sort of identity provider are you using?  The one that comes with ASP.NET MVC Core?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34934378

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `SecurityStamp` property of type `GUID` to users model and set `SecurityStamp` to `cookie` or `jwt` token.

then when a user login, you must change the `SecurityStamp` value to a new value and save `SecurityStamp` to cookie and any time user send a request to application you must check `SecurityStamp` saved in cookie with `SecurityStamp` of users in database. and if these properties wasn't equal togeter you must reject user and set sign out user.

```cs
public static async Task ValidateAsync(CookieValidatePrincipalContext context)
{
    context = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
    var claimsIdentity = context.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
    if(claimsIdentity?.Claims == null || !claimsIdentity.Claims.Any())
    {
        await RejectPrincipal();
        return;
    }
    UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<UserManager<IdentityUser>>();
    var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(context.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier));
    if (user == null || user.SecurityStamp != context.Principal.FindFirst(new ClaimsIdentityOptions().SecurityStampClaimType)?.Value)
    {
        await RejectPrincipal();
        return;
    }
    async Task RejectPrincipal()
    {
        context.RejectPrincipal();
        await context.HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }
}
```

In startup class pass `ValidateAsync` method to `OnValidatePrincipal` and set `ValidationInterval` to zero.

```cs
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    //
    options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
    {
        OnValidatePrincipal = ValidateAsync
    };
}).Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ValidationInterval = TimeSpan.Zero;
});
```

finally in your method just update `SecurityStamp` value like this:

```cs
    public async Task SetExpired()
    {
        foreach(var item in _db.Institution)
        {
            if (item.SubscriptionEndDate != null)
            {
                if (item.SubscriptionEndDate == DateTime.Today) 
                {
                    item.Status = SD.StatusExpired;

                  //Here I want to check if the user is logged in, then force logout should be done.     
                  Guid securityStamp = Guid.NewGuid();
                  item.SecurityStamp = securityStamp;

                }
            }
        }
        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

Comment: Where should I put the 'ValidateAsync'?

Comment: Create `ValidateAsync` method inside of `ConfigureService` method in startup class and pass `ValidateAsync` to `OnValidatePrincipal ` in `options.Events` cookie

Comment: Still not getting this :(.. I mean should I separate the ValidateAsync(CookieValidatePrincipalContext context) in different class under "Services" folder for example?  .. You said inside configureServices but how is this ?